# How to include javascript and css files in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to use a 3rd party javascript control, [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).  The way I am reading the documentations is this:

In the zip file from Owl Carousel there is a folder called owlcarousel that contains the javascript and another folder that contains all the supporting files which need to be copied to /modules/base-accelerator/yacceleratorstorefront/web/webroot/_ui/responsive/common.  Then I simply need to go into the javaScript.tag file and add this line towards the end of the file:

```
<script src="${commonResourcePathHtml}/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Upon trying that, I get all sorts of loading errors and no images are display, even without using the control.  So my question is:

1. What is the correct approach to include a 3rd party javascript?
2. Is there any way to control which pages actually get a javascript file or do simply ALL the pages get ALL the javascript includes?

Answer (score 4):

See if "Storefront Web Application Deconstructed" will help: https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/1905/en-US/8af03fda8669101491e4aac2acaeb2dd.html

- web/webroot

  - _ui: Contains the JavaScript and CSS styling for the current theme.

    - shared/js: Shared JavaScript used by desktop and responsive pages.
    - responsive/common: Commonly used style sheets, JavaScript libraries and images.
    - responsive/theme-alpha: The blue theme definition.
    - responsive/theme-lambda: The black theme definition.
- WEB-INF

  - _ui-src: Contains JS testing, full libraries, and the Less files used to generate the CSS for a theme.
  - common/tld: The tag library descriptor files for the CMS and ycommerce tags.
  - config: Spring application context files.
  - lib: The libraries required by the storefront.
  - messages: The localization files.
  - tags: The tags that are used within views.
  - views: The JSP pages, fragments and CMS components.

Comment: That was a GREAT link, I read the whole thing and learned a TON!  Thank you, but... it does not answer the question I asked,  I have learned some new perspectives so I am going to go tweak my original question a bit.  If you don't mind reviewing that and seeing if that helps clarify what I am really asking :)